# Dockerfile: why doesn't the bash command work?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I'd like to learn the Dockerfile from a very simple start, so here's my Dockfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

however, after building the image and run the container, I find that I can't run the bash commands. For example, if I type:

```
# clear
```

The container seems to get stuck running in an infinite loop.
So why does that happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you add a -it to your docker run command?  `docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash ubuntu -c "clear"` seems to work...

Comment: Please add the command that you used to run the container, and the output in your container's bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you running the container? Note that you have to pass the options `-i` in order to keep STDIN open and the `-t` to allocate a pseudo-TTY.

Below you can find an example:

> docker run -i -t my-image

Comment: Yeas, I forget to add -i while running the container! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

docker run -it ubuntu

Post this command, you will have a prompt like:

root@26f9e7a42517:/#